# MySQL Group By & Return Largest Group

Tags: mysql, group-by

I'm looking for a way to run a query that does a group by and then gives me what the largest group is.

For instance, if I had a table with a bunch of types of fruit and I queried that table with a group by fruit query and the most instances were apples, the largest group would be apples and it would return apples.

Make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try something like:

```
SELECT fruit FROM (
    SELECT fruit, COUNT(*) AS `count`
    FROM fruits
    GROUP BY fruit
) sub
ORDER BY `count` DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you want?

```
select fruit
from fruits f
group by fruit
order by count(*) desc
limit 1
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to used subselects

```
SELECT fruit, COUNT(fruit) as `count`
FROM fruits
GROUP BY fruit
ORDER BY `count` DESC
```